# How can I convert/merge a primary partition into the extended?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I don't know if I am the only fool out here but I want to have only one partition as a `primary` and other(s) *under* `extended`.

Currently I have disk state as:
[image]

Is there any way I can merge the `RAW` partition which is a primary partition as if now into that 172.79GB Free Space, so that I can make a single new `Logical` drive of size (172.79+48.83) GB under that extended partition?

I tried deleting the primary partition but it results in a different `Unallocated` space rather than mixing up with the free space.

I hope I am clear with my question. I also searched for relevant matter on web but could not found one useful.

Also your valuable suggestions are most welcome if I am not going on correct way.

I am on `Windows 7 Ultimate x64`, and its a 500GB SATA HDD.

Comment: You are not going to manage what you want without some major data moving which the tools built into windows don't do.

Comment: @Asif please visit these answers and Green the correct answer and +1 who answered correct

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi Please don't beg people for upvotes or accepting answers. If they find your posts useful, they will. Constantly asking for upvotes is considered rude.

Answer (score 2):

1) Backup all your data in the D: and E: partitions somewhere off-disk.
2) Delete all partitions except your first primary.
3) Recreate an extended and however many logical partitions you wish in the unallocated
   space beyond your first.
4) Restore your filesystems/data to the new logical partitions.

There is very large body of reported failures in moving NTFS filesystems to the "left".

There may be a good reason Windows utilities will not attempt the task.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the Windows on-board tools, but the [Minitool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) worked for me for a similar task.

I would suggest to delete the 48GB empty partition and then extend the extended partition to use the free space in front of it.  Then in a second step using the same software to move the logical partitions (D: and E: drives) to the beginning of the extended partition.

The whole thing should not be very difficult or risky, but whenever you are doing modifications like this, you are risking of loosing data.  So I would recommend to either make a backup befaore starting, or at least temporarily use the 172GB free space to create a temporary partition to back up the data before moving it.  However this backup might still get lost, when resizing the logical partition goes wrong.

To comment on your sentence:

> I tried deleting the primary partition but it results in a different Unallocated space rather than mixing up with the free space.

This is correct, because the space that was freed by deleting the primary partition was outside the extended partition, whereas the 172 GB were inside the extended partition.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way.

Head to Disk Management

Right click on the drives that you want the free space to merge into.

Select Extend Drives

Choose the Free Space drive from the selection box.

Voila! You're done

Answer (score -1):

[Acronis true image 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronis) backup and when you want to restore you can change the primary to extended

or logical to primary or etc.